# Standard practice for reporting errors in Winforms

Tags: vb.net, winforms, error-handling

I'm developing a password generator in VB.NET Windows Forms that will generate a [correct-horse style password](http://xkcd.com/936/) with certain user-inputted parameters. I haven't fully grokked event-driven programming. I have a procedural function that generates the password, and there are several possible situations in which errors could arise from user input. For example, if the user enters a value for "minimum characters" higher than "maximum characters", that should be disallowed and the user needs to fix their input. Or if the user has specified that hyphens both should not be allowed and are required to be in the password. Errors could pop up in multiple places and I'm not sure what the most efficient way of dealing with them is, with program flow in mind.

Is there a standard way of reporting errors in Winforms, and particularly when in the middle of a function? Should I use a MsgBox and then exit the function? Should I have a label already prepared and change it to an appropriate error message, and *then* exit the function? Or should I be putting error handling in a separate function, and only running the password generating function once I've ascertained the user hasn't made any stupids?

I haven't got any code because I haven't written it yet, although I've got the basic algorithm, form and controls. I'm not sure what would be most relevant; let me know and I'll post it.

Comment: "the user" doesnt sound like it has to be the end user, but a developer using Your Thing in their code, in which case yours might be a class library (or component) to create the PWs.  Dev sets the props like min/max then does `newPW = myCHorse.GetPassword()`.  Leaving the actual user to set the rules for a PW sounds like a disaster.

Comment: The idea is that the user selects whatever password restrictions they have to use for a particular service. If Company X wants your password to have at least one number, maximum 32 characters, etc. then the user can set those parameters and generate a random password that complies with Company X's restrictions. The end user will be me. I thought it would make choosing passwords more fun (read: less stressful.)

Comment: If possible, you should be validating the input before using it.  One option is to use an `ErrorProvider` component to place an error icon next to fields with issues that will display a message in a tool tip when moused-over.  You can simply disable the ``Button` that invokes the method that uses the data if any errors are present.

Comment: You might also consider using the `Validating` event to prevent the user leaving a particular control while it contains invalid data.  That might not be appropriate for something like conflicting `CheckBox` controls but for `TextBox` controls and the like it might be OK.